# Why can I not use a while loop to draw a chessboard on my desktop, but can on my laptop?

Tags: java, swing, draw, drawable

I'm trying to make a chess board using a while loop. However when I use a while loop, the tiles show up for a second and then they disappear.

The code for the panel

```
package chess;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChessBoard extends JPanel{

    public int tileSize = 90;
    public int cols = 8;
    public int rows = 8;
    public int maxCols = cols * tileSize;
    public int maxRows = rows * tileSize;
    TileManager tileM = new TileManager(this);
    
    ChessBoard(){
        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxCols, maxRows));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true); 
        this.setFocusable(true); 
        
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        tileM.drawTiles(g2);
        
    }

}
```

the code for the drawing

```
package chess;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TileManager {

    ChessBoard cb;
    public static int [] types = new int[10];
    private static int rows = 0;
    private static int cols = 0;
    private boolean c = true;
    String [] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};
    String [] num = {"8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
    
    TileManager(ChessBoard cb){
        
        this.cb = cb;
        
    }
    
    public void drawTiles(Graphics g) {
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        while (rows < cb.rows && cols < cb.cols) {
            
            if (c)  g.setColor(Color.white);
            if (!c) g.setColor(Color.black);
            
            g2.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 20));
            g2.fillRect(cols * cb.tileSize, rows * cb.tileSize, cb.tileSize, cb.tileSize);
            g2.setColor(Color.green);
            g2.drawString(alpha[cols], 5 + cols * cb.tileSize, 20 + rows * cb.tileSize);
            g2.drawString(num[rows], 75 + cols * cb.tileSize, 85 + rows * cb.tileSize);
            
            c = !c;
            cols++;

            if (cols == 8) {
                
                c = !c;
                cols = 0;
                rows++;
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The weird thing about this is that this code works perfectly on my laptop, but when I exported it to my desktop, it has this problem.
[this is what it looks like on my laptop, which weirdly works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2d96.png)
[this is what it looks like on my desktop, and it shows the board correctly for a split second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Zap.png)

Comment: _"when I exported it to my desktop"_ - How? That may be part of the problem.  Also, do you have the same JRE/JDK on both systems?  What about OS versions?  Lots of important details missing...

Comment: Oops, I was not reading as carefully as I should. Tricky variable names though

Comment: im using java echlipse on both computers and same os versions. I don't think it's a problem with the system, because i've done a similar thing using a while loop to create tiles in a different game on the desktop. I exported the file using the export thing on java echlipse as well.

Comment: Did you copy the compiled files over, or did you copy the source code and recompile?

Comment: i just downloaded it as a zip on echlipse and then imported. So the code is the exact same and I went through and checked. I don't know why, but the code is the same, but the output is different

Answer (score 1):

This is problematic on a number of levels...

```
public class TileManager {

    private static int rows = 0;
    private static int cols = 0;

    //...
    public void drawTiles(Graphics g) {
        //...
        while (rows < cb.rows && cols < cb.cols) {
```

Ask yourself the question, what happens on the next paint pass?

Painting in Swing is destructive.  That is, on each new paint pass, you're expected to completely repaint the state of the component, from scratch.

One of the things `paintComponent` will do is fill the `Graphics` context with the background color of the component.

So, on subsequent paint passes, `rows` and `cols` are already `>=` `cb.rows` and `cb.cols` so you delegate will paint nothing.

First, remove `static`, it's not doing your any favours in this context and will probably cause you more issues then it solves.  Second, `rows` and `cols` don't need to be instance level variables, their only function is to support the painting of the grid, so you can make then local variables instead.

For example...

```
public class TileManager {

    ChessBoard cb;
    public int[] types = new int[10];
    private boolean c = true;
    String[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};
    String[] num = {"8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};

    TileManager(ChessBoard cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
    }

    public void drawTiles(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;

        while (rows < cb.rows && cols < cb.cols) {

            if (c) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
            }
            if (!c) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }

            g2.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 20));
            g2.fillRect(cols * cb.tileSize, rows * cb.tileSize, cb.tileSize, cb.tileSize);
            g2.setColor(Color.green);
            g2.drawString(alpha[cols], 5 + cols * cb.tileSize, 20 + rows * cb.tileSize);
            g2.drawString(num[rows], 75 + cols * cb.tileSize, 85 + rows * cb.tileSize);

            c = !c;
            cols++;

            if (cols == 8) {

                c = !c;
                cols = 0;
                rows++;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I, personally, would consider it bad practice to pass `TileManager` an instance of `ChessBoard`, you're exposing WAY more functionality to `TileManager` then it has any responsibility for managing.

As the code stands, I don't see any reason for it, but if you did need `TileManager` to pull information from it, I'd consider writing an `interface` which defined the contract, or, simply have `ChessBoard` set the properties of the `TileManager`.  Any return communication should be done via an observer pattern (so `TileManager` and tell, who ever is interested, that some has happened)

I would suggest paying closer attention to [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html).

As to the question of "why" it works on one platform and not another, welcome to the wonderful world of, that's how different platforms work - but some thing is triggering Swing to perform one or more paint passes after the initial paint pass.

When I tested it (on MacOS), it worked right up to the moment I tried re-sizing the window.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. As I was cleaning up the code, I also inadvertently fixed the problem, which was just making the rows and cols local variables. For some reason this fixed the problem. I also wanted a tile manager because I wanted to have pixel art for the tiles, so reading them would be more organized if I had the manager.

Comment: @NotQuiteSoInvisible I'm not saying you can't have the delegate and there's a lot of context missing, what I'm saying is it's probably a bad idea to pass it an instance of `ChessBoard` - `ChessBoard` is a component with a lot of functionality that `TileManager` doesn't really need access to - better to define a contract for `TileManager` via a `interface`, just saying